# Is there a way to prevent a background-image from being resized when zooming the page?

Tags: css, image, background-image, fixed-width

The background-image is just a simple pattern that looks best at 100%.
Is there a way to prevent such a background-image from being resized when zooming the page?

Answer (score 0):

zoom is browser feature and it's just enlarge everything you see in your browser so there is nothing you can do to keep the size of the images fixed

Answer (score 0):

you could probably try pulling in an image into your HTML document instead:

```
<div id="bg-img">
    <img src="images/bg-img.jpg">
</div>
```

then going on to your CSS, you could apply the following style to that div holding the image:

```
#bg-img{
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:-4;
 }
```

the above style set will set your image to fit nicely into any browsers and prevent the background-image from resizing or expanding up to about 3 times of the zoom. be sure to fill in the appropriate value for the min-width so that in the event that the browser is resized, the image will maintain the correct proportion by resizing or cropping off.

Comment: how does it not work on chrome and safari? as in what errors are occurring in the two browsers? ive applied the similar method to a couple of sites and there are working fine regardless of the browser type.. so unless you can specify the problem, it'll be pretty difficult to debug.

Comment: a sample of your current codes after the revisions would also be good :)